# Clojure library for TGA

Tags: clojure, tga

I want to create a simple [TGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA) file, for example drawing a line. I didn't find a Clojure library for this, although I found similar libraries for Common Lisp (cl-tga, targa).

Is there any Clojure library to create TGA files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the very good [Quil](http://quil.info/) library, a wrapper around the very good [Processing](https://processing.org/) Java library, see for example http://quil.info/api/image/rendering.

Note on the other hand that Quil, like Processing, draws in a loop, so you have to get used to it. This blog post https://www.tylerlhobbs.com/writings/using-quil-for-artwork explains how to use Quil to generate a single image (as opposed to an animation).

Comment: I don't know the Java version, but the quality of the JavaScript version (processing.js) leaves a lot to be desired.